# Redux, Provider and decorators

Tags: reactjs, redux, decorator, react-redux

I'm new with redux, and i'm trying to build my app with it. I created reducers file, the combine reducers file, the components, the actions, etc
But when i start my server i get *Unexpected token* where *@connect()* is called.

Let see my code:

**Main.js**

```
 ...
 import { Provider } from "react-redux";
 ...
 ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
 );
```

**Login.js**

```
...
@connect((store) => {
  return {
    modal: store.showModal,
  };
})

class ModalLogin extends React.Component {
 ...
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
   context: path.join(__dirname, "app"),
   devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
   entry: "./main.js",
   module: {
     loaders: [
       {
         test: /\.jsx?$/,
         exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         query: {
           presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
           plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
        }
      }
    ]
   },
   output: {
     path: __dirname + "/public/js/",
     filename: "bundle.js"
   },
   plugins: debug ? [] : [
     new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
     new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
     new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false  }),
  ],
};
```

And i'm following this [Tutorial](https://github.com/learncodeacademy/react-js-tutorials/tree/master/5-redux-react/src/js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That suggests that the decorator transform isn't set up correctly.  I do see that you have `transform-decorators-legacy` in there, but I'd guess something about the ordering isn't correct.

The Redux team generally advises *not* using decorators, since they are still an unstable proposal, and both the spec and the compiler plugins have been changing.  Use `connect` as a function instead:  `export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(MyComponent)`.

Also, the easiest way to get up and running with a React application build environment is to use the [Create-React-App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) tool.  It creates a working project environment with build tools set up for you, no configuration that you have to manage yourself, and a bunch of nice developer experience features to help you get started.